# I need help putting formulas into a google sheet using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that includes many formulas.  I want to use a script to put the formulas in instead of having them in the cells so that it can't be accidentally deleted.  I know I can protect cells, but that only prevents other people from deleting them.  I don't want to delete them by accident either.  I have this line:
range.setFormula('=arrayformula(IF(ISBLANK(C6:C13),"",VLOOKUP(C6:C13,'D & D Stats'!$A$2:$B$19,2,FALSE())))');

GAS says it has a syntax error, but when I use the formula directly in the cell:

=arrayformula(IF(ISBLANK(C6:C13),"",VLOOKUP(C6:C13,'D & D Stats'!$A$2:$B$19,2,FALSE())))

it works fine.  According to a tutorial I saw, I should only need to put the formula inside the  range.setFormula(' ');  for it to work, but that way it throws a syntax error.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is for a character sheet for D&D.  I need the script to put the formulas on each sheet for a character, so has to work on whatever sheet is active by any user.  Here is a link to the sample sheets with the scripts that are already in use.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fFyww9vpeICfLNUf32bLIdudDQoDbgaEc5xk54FwwC4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: My sheet is not a typical sheet used for business type things.  I don't believe I have any need for the getLastRow() method.  I am just trying to script the formulas so if it is accidentally deleted, I can run the script and it would replace it.  The formulas themselves work fine in the cells.  Just want to automate putting them in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be quote and double quote in the formula not well enclosing there : `range.setFormula('=arrayformula(IF(ISBLANK(C6:C13),"",VLOOKUP(C6:C13,'D & D Stats'!$A$2:$B$19,2,FALSE())))');`

As help to grasp how enclose a string:

- ' " ' = "
- " ' " = '
- 'It's great' = It (s great is syntax error)
- "It's great" = It's great
- `"It's great", said o'reyley` = "It's great", said o'reyley

you should try using string interpolation char ` :

```
range.setFormula(`=arrayformula(IF(ISBLANK(C6:C13),"",VLOOKUP(C6:C13,'D & D Stats'!$A$2:$B$19,2,FALSE())))`);
```

or with double quote "

```
range.setFormula("=arrayformula(IF(ISBLANK(C6:C13),'',VLOOKUP(C6:C13,'D & D Stats'!$A$2:$B$19,2,FALSE())))");
```

As personal suggestion, you should make something easier to maintain.

Like an hidden sheet with all you formula in and the script will only copy paste from the hidden sheet to the visible one (like backup). In that way if you have any update, it can be done in the hidden sheet.

Comment: I am a rookie working with the scripts.  I have a document with all of my formulas in case one gets deleted, but I was hoping for a script because I thought I could run the script and it would replace the formula.

I started a function called addForm and I would like it to work similar to the setSpells function that checks the sheet name and runs on any new sheets I make for characters.  I just have to put the new sheet names in the inSheets array so that it will work.  Obviously I didn't write that function.  Someone on here helped me with that. Any help doing that would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay then you can record a macro for that , in extension tab you can find record macro. Juste double click on a cell an copy paste you value (very important to capy paste the value, not the cell). Once it's done you can stop the macro recording : you have a scrip making exactly what you are expecting